# In python : How to perform a HTTP request, and connect with a websocket, through the same connection?

Tags: python, http, websocket, connection, request

I am trying to connect to a website through a program, whose authentification protocol appears to be the following :

- Connect to the websocket.
- Receive crucial data for logging in.
- Make a HTTP request with username/password/some of the datas THROUGH THIS CONNECTION.

This means that if i open another connection, the data linked to this connection, according to the server, will be different.
For exemple, receiving the data through the websocket, and doing a HTTP request with a browser will not work, as the browser is another connection.

By connection, i mean what is created at the start of the program, for exemple :

*ws2= websocket.create_connection("ws://sim.smogon.com:8000/showdown/websocket")* for the websocket module

*h1 = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.cwi.nl')* for the http module.

My problem is that i have to create 2 different connections to connect to websocket and make a http request. This means that the http request will not work with the websocket received data.
How to make these 2 connections the same ? Or, simplier said : how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Once a HTTP Request has been upgraded to a Websocket you can no longer perform HTTP Requests over that channel. The protocol was not designed that way.